# Issues with multiple ethernet interfaces

Tags: networking, ethernet, iptables, interface

I am trying to setup my Ubuntu box with 2 ethernet interfaces(one has a public IP and the other is connected to my internal network).

I have flushed my IPtables(using sudo iptables -F) and yet I can't connect to the public IP from the Internet.

- When I am on the internal network I can ping to both, the public and private IPs. [Our internal network is setup in a way that it knows the subnet of my public IP]
- I can't ping to the public IP from the Internet. I checked the tcpdump at this point, and I could see SYNs **to** the public IP but no SYN-ACKs being sent back.
- On disconnecting the ethernet cable for the internal network, I can in fact ping to the public IP.

Comment: Please append the routing table when the private iface is plugged/unplugged.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me there :) My routing table had rules to send packets from one interface to the other which was causing the issue.

Comment: I expected something like this. Consider writing a short answer to your question and accept it. Someone might come across the same problem and benefit from your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my routing tables using

```
route -n
```

The routes suggested that the packets coming from eth1(interface having the  public ip) were being sent to eth0(interface having the private ip) and were hence being dropped.

After that it was just about setting up the right routes.